# illegal bit size in pattern matching

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

i have field and must check that it have such view <<"{{name_of_field}}">>

i make

```
try
    <<"{{", _/binary>> = FieldName
  catch
    _:_ ->
      throw(error)
  end,
  Size = byte_size(FieldName),
  try
    <<_:(Size-2)/binary, "}}">> = FieldName
  catch
    _:_ ->
      throw(error)
  end
```

and get "* 1: illegal bit size" when match Tail of FieldName

Answer (score 2):

looks good
i've find solution

The expression (Size-2) is supported when constructing a binary. This 
is definitely a pattern matching, so as stated above: the Size must be a 
constant expression or a variable. Not an expression to be evaluated at 
runtime.

all answer
http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-December/071145.html